# How to understand empty second parameter to pandas DataFrame.loc

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Hi I am looking for help to understand the behaviour caused by not having/having an empty second parameter to pandas `DataFrame.loc` method

Consider the following:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a', 1, 'x'),('a', 2, 'y'),('b', 1, 'x')]), data={'col_1':[1, 2, 3]})
df
```

Output:

|  |  |  | col_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | x | 1 |
|  | 2 | y | 2 |
| b | 1 | x | 3 |

If I access rows with `df.loc[(slice(None), 1, slice(None))]` the returned result has a different index:

|  |  | col_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | x | 1 |
| b | x | 3 |

The index columns are preserved where the tuple values are `slice(None)` and the index column is dropped where the value is explcitly specified.

However, if I put a comma after the restricting tuple, the index is preserved: `df.loc[(slice(None), 1, slice(None)),]` yields:

|  |  |  | col_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | x | 1 |
| b | 1 | x | 3 |

I'd be grateful if anyone could explain what is the difference in the inputs `(slice(None), 1, slice(None))`and `(slice(None), 1, slice(None)),` and why does this cause a difference in the outputs

Answer (score 0):

Here Pandas is waiting for you to specify a 2nd condition, take the below as a example where a 2nd column is added.

```
import pandas as pd

tuples = [('a', 1, 'x'),('a', 2, 'y'),('b', 1, 'x')]
data1 = {'col_1':[1, 2, 3],'col_2':[4, 5, 6]}

df=pd.DataFrame(index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples), data=data1 )

x = df.loc [ ( slice(None), 1, slice(None) ) ]
y = (df.loc [ ( slice(None), 1, slice(None) ) , 'col_2' ])
z = (df.loc [ ( slice(None), 1, slice(None) ) , 'col_2' ]).loc [ ( slice(None), 1, slice(None) ) ]

print('2 Indexes here \n' ,x,'\n',x.index,'\n')
print('3 indexes here \n' ,y,'\n',y.index,'\n')
print('2 indexes here \n' ,z,'\n',z.index)
```

```
Outputs :
2 Indexes here 
      col_1  col_2
a x      1      4
b x      3      6 
MultiIndex([('a', 'x'),('b', 'x')],) 

3 indexes here 
a  1  x    4
b  1  x    6
Name: col_2, dtype: int64 
MultiIndex([('a', 1, 'x'),('b', 1, 'x')],) 

2 indexes here 
a  x    4
b  x    6
Name: col_2, dtype: int64 
MultiIndex([('a', 'x'),('b', 'x')],)
```

The first time where no comma is present, you have stated you want only df.loc[(slice(None),1,slice(None))]. So pandas shows you a and x.

If you specify what you want say eg print(df.loc [( slice(None), 1, 'x' )]

```
It will output only 1 index because you have made it clear what you want.
   col_1  col_2
a      1      4
b      3      6 
Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Whereas in the 2nd time slicing you are mentioning you want column 2 specifically ! So pandas shows the first and 2nd index.

Hope my explanation is clear !